# In MySql how to find what is causing DB connection increase

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

These is a sudden increase in DB Connections in MySql. What query can I run to find which which user is creating the connection and what query is being run?

[image]

Comment: Usually, in most of the cases, the app server makes the connection by utilizing the already created thread (for connection pooling), so the first step to get some information about the actors who are performing the activities from the app server.